# Puppet Enterprise or puppet open source

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

How to determine from the puppet master whether the installed version is opensource or enterprise?

Thanks,
Lokesh

Comment: Why do you want to make this determination inside Puppet?  And which version do you want -- that of the agent or that of the master?

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious look at the "puppetversion" fact
on enterprise

```
# /usr/local/bin/facter puppetversion
3.4.3 (Puppet Enterprise 3.2.0)
```

on open source

```
# facter puppetversion
3.7.3
```

The fact is easily available in manifests

Alternative method

```
puppet config print config
```

if it is `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`
then it's probably open source puppet

if it is 
`/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf`
probably enterprise

You could also check for those files and if they existed.  Of course the file location is not compulsary, these are just defaults

Comment: I checked the command facter puppetversion, it looks like it has been removed in the latest version of pe2015 and facter 3.1, is there any other command which gives the exact version?

Comment: Also facter -p puppetversion, is just giving the version  it is not showing whether it is enterprise or not.

Comment: @Lokn sorry only have that old version of puppet enterprise so can't help you.  Upgrade has been kicked into Q2 2016 :(